# How to merge vertices with same properties in Gremlin?

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

Basically If I have a graph where Rob has an apple and Anna also has an apple like that:

Rob --has-->apple
Anna --has-->apple

which is obviously a mistake. I only want one 'apple' vertex with edges from both Rob and Anna like that:
 Rob --has--> apple <--has--Anna

is there an option in Gremlin to 'merge' all vertices's with the label 'apple' and still have the edges?
Sorry for this bad question, english isn't my first language and I am fairly new at this TT
hope someone can help though...

Answer (score 0):

Not in Cypher you would do

```
start Rob=node(1), Anna=node(2) match Rob-[:has]->apple<-[:has]-Anna return apple
```

I think Gremlin would be something like

```
rob=1
anna=2
t = new Table()
g.v(rob).out('has').as('apple').in('has').filter{it.id==anna}.table(t,['apple']){it.name}.iterate()
```

HTH

/peter

Answer (score 0):

If the amount of apples can fit into main memory, then you can do the following.

```
apples = [] as Set
g.id(T.v)[[type:'apple']].each{apples.add(it)}
apple = g.addVertex()
apples.each{it.map.each{k,v -> apple[k] = v}
apples.each{it.outE.each{g.addEdge(apple, it.inVertex, it.label)}
apples.each{it.inE.each{g.addEdge(apple, it.outVertex, it.label)}
apples.each{g.removeVertex(it)}
```

Each line does the following:

1. Create an in-memory set of apples.
2. Find all the apples in the graph you want to merge (I don't know your data model so this is the best assumption).
3. Create a new apple vertex (the merge vertex).
4. For each of the apples, set the respective properties of the new apple vertex (may overwrite older apple properties)
5. For each outgoing edge, add a similar edge from the merge apple.
6. For each incoming edge, add a similar edge to the merge apple.
7. Remove all the apples (except the new merge apple).

Be smart about transactions when you do this:
   https://github.com/tinkerpop/blueprints/wiki/Graph-Transactions